# How do I obtain the hellfire ring materials

Tags: diablo-iii, xbox-360

I obtained the hellfire ring recipe in Diablo 3 (base game, no DLCs) and I don't know how to get the materials to craft it.

Is it meant to only be crafted in the RoS expansion or are the ingredients obtainable in the COW level?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.icy-veins.com/d3/hellfire-amulet-and-ring-crafting-guide) first

Comment: So essentially, I must get the RoS expansion?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, if none of these options are available in the vanilla, then yes, but I really doubt they would give you the recipes but not allow you to have the rest of the ingredients.

Comment: Looks like I'll be doing a lot of farming and searching!

Comment: The infernal machines require level 70 to use. Without buying the RoS expansion you cannot get to level 70 to use them. I would post this as an answer but I do remember seeing level 60 versions of the rings. I'm not sure if these are obtainable in the base game, or if they are just left over from pre-RoS and not obtainable same as the level 70 versions.

Comment: You can get the level 60 versions from squirt for 100,000 gold. I have the most recent update btw. Don't the paragon levels count as going up to there or are they just unique and give 4% to gold and magic find?

Comment: It sounds like you're on console, correct?  The answer may be different now between console/PC for pre-RoS material.

Comment: Yeah I'm on Xbox 360. That's why I'm confused cause I've looked a lot on the Internet and they've all led to RoS. I might have missed something, which is why I asked